# Unable to update Mac OS 10.7.5

Tags: macos, mac, software-update

I am trying update my iMac OS from 10.7 to 10.7.5. I've downloaded the `MacOSXUpdCombo10.7.5.dmg` file, but when updating, it gives an error like:

> Mac OS X Update Combined can't be installed on this disk. This volume does not meet the requirements for this update.

What can I do to successfully update the OS?

Comment: Have you already tried updating using Software Update ( Apple-menu > Software Update)? If yes, what happened? Have you already tried booting the Mac from the Recovery partition and running Disk Utility's 'Repair Disk' function? (Restart Mac while keeping Option(Alt) key pressed, click 'Recovery HD'...)

Comment: i tried it but Mac OS not updated when i am updated Apple-menu > Software Update)

Comment: How much space do you have on the disk?

Comment: Repairing your disk using Disk Utility should help. If it doesn't, try using the 10.7.3 Combo /Client/ Update (http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1484) which is known to help.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your have downloaded the correct combo updater:

- OS X **Server** should have the 10.7.5 **Server** Combo updater = [DL1585](http://support.apple.com/kb/DL1585) ≈ [1.99 GB](http://support.apple.com/downloads/DL1585/en_US/MacOSXServerUpdCombo10.7.5.dmg)
- OS X **Client** should have the 10.7.5 **Client** Combo updater = [DL1582](http://support.apple.com/kb/dl1582) ≈ [1.91 GB](http://support.apple.com/downloads/DL1582/en_US/MacOSXUpdCombo10.7.5.dmg)

---

To determine whether the client or server version is installed on your Mac, use the Terminal command: `$ /usr/bin/sw_vers`

Example output for 10.7.5 Server:

```
ProductName:    Mac OS X Server
ProductVersion: 10.7.5
BuildVersion:   11G63
```